# Place two elements together without using float

Tags: php, html, css

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #success
    {
        color: #f0f0f0;
        position: relative;
        top: 3%;
        left: 50%;

        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;  
    }
    #errors {
        color: #b81d18;
        position: relative;
        top: 3%;
        left: 15%;

        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
if (isset($_POST['login']))
{
    $username = trim($_POST['login_username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['login_password']);

    $login = login($username, $password); 
    if ($login === FALSE)
    {
        $errors[] = 'That username/password combination is incorrect.';
        $errors_1 = output_errors($errors);
        echo "<div id='errors'> $errors_1</div>";
        $success[] = "You are logged in as a guest";
        $success_1 = output_errors($success)
        echo <div id='success'>$success_1</div>
    }
}

<form id="password_form" action="" method="post">
    Username: </br>
    <input type="text" name="login_username" value="<?php echo $_POST['login_username']; ?>"> 
    </br>
    Password:</br> 
    <input type="password" name="login_password">
    </br>
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log in">  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Above is my code. I want to be able to display the error div and success div side by side. The reason I cannot use float is because when the error or success div are outputted, the form is moved down and the error are displayed above the form. If I use float, then the form no longer moves down when the error div is displayed and I do not want that to happen. The reason why they are two separate divs is because each div has its own color. Any suggestions on how to do this or a way to put all errors and success messages into one array but give them their respective color when outputted.

Comment: How can there be a successful login and an error at the same time?

Comment: Have you tried making a div that contains both of them. Then, put one on the left and one on the right of that div.

Comment: You could use bootstrap and use the grid system.

Comment: PHP is irrelevant. Please only post the resulting HTML.

Comment: Where are your php opening and closing tags or do you have them in your actual code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `float` just fine. You just need to clear the float of your response messages is all.

Here is the key ingrediant:

```css
#password_form {
     clear: left;
}
```

Full example with **float**. Remove the `#error` DIV or `#success` DIV and everything will stay in place.

```css
#success, #errors {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
#success {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
#errors {
    background-color: #b81d18;
    }
#password_form {
    clear: left;
}
```

```html
<!-- comment out or remove one of the DIVs below to test -->
<div id="success">Success</div>
<div id="errors">Error</div>

<form id="password_form" action="" method="post">
    Username: </br>
    <input type="text" name="login_username" value=""> 
    </br>
    Password:</br> 
    <input type="password" name="login_password">
    </br>
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log in">  
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display: inline-block` on the div's. Like this:

```
#success
{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #f0f0f0;
    position: relative;
    top: 3%;
    left: 50%;

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;  
}
#errors {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #b81d18;
    position: relative;
    top: 3%;
    left: 15%;

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```